# Placeholder element for non-affiliated HTML5 data attributes?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

I have a small set of structured data items that I would like embedded in an HTML document. The data is used by some JavaScript for interacting with the page, but is otherwise hidden.

I have considered using HTML5 data attributes, but I am unsure which element is most suitable for affixing stray data. I thought of using `div` elements, like so:

```
<div data-make="Ford"  data-model="Fusion"  data-year="2005"></div>
<div data-make="Chevy" data-model="Volt"    data-year="2010"></div>
<div data-make="Honda" data-model="Insight" data-year="2010"></div>
```

This is a kludge, since the content model of the `div` element is flow content, which recommends at least one descendent. I also considered using an unordered list, but this is also a kludge for the same reason, since the content model of the `li` element is also flow content.

I have searched for best practices regarding HTML5 data attributes, but since these attributes are relatively new and not yet in common use, little information is available.

Any other recommendations for a placeholder element to which to affix stray data attributes? Or am I going about this all wrong? Using something like JSON seems heavy handed for my needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe you tend to interpret the html5 spec too strictly. quoted from [fc](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#flow-content-0):

> This requirement is not a hard requirement

so you might cling to attributing `div` elements. if you add a unique class css-attributed with `'display:none'` to your dummy elements, they will not be rendered thus making the intricacies of flow content kind of moot.
if you feel more comfortable with phrasing content ([pc](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#phrasing-content)), use empty `span` elements instead.

alternatively, the `meta`-tag might be an option:

```
<meta itemprop="data" content="dummy" data="..."/>
```

note that `meta`-tags are allowed in the `body` of a html5 doc ([meta](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-meta-element)). while the `itemprop` attribute ([ip](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#names%3a-the-itemprop-attribute)) is necessary for the use as a generic data container, according to the specs, a `content` attribute ist not strictly necessary - however, you could always resort to some dummy string.

hope this helps,

best regards, carsten

Comment: I understand that non-empty flow content is a suggestion rather than a requirement. However, both examples in the spec suggest empty flow content as a placeholder for content that will be dynamically added. Further, the spec discourages `div` elements as a matter of practice, saying that they should be elements of last resort (though I disagree).

Comment: The microdata approach is an interesting one. It would work since `meta` elements with the `itemprop` attribute can be used anywhere phrasing content is allowed. Groups could be created by adding an `itemscope` to a common parent of meta elements. Unfortunately, the microdata API is not yet supported, which makes it less convenient than `data` attributes.

Comment: Decided that microdata with `meta` elements is the way to go.